# Fix "error processing archive […] Operation not permitted" during apt upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, xorg, dpkg

Can somebody please help me fix this error of packages. I tried almost everything present on the internet. I have already tried the "--fix-broken" and "-f" command.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fontconfig fonts-droid-fallback fonts-noto-mono fonts-urw-base35 gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme imagemagick-6-common
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdjvulibre-text
  libdjvulibre21 libfftw3-double3 libgraphite2-3 libgs9 libgs9-common libharfbuzz0b libice6 libijs-0.35 libilmbase24
  libimagequant0 libjbig2dec0 liblcms2-2 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libnetpbm10 libopenexr24 libopenjp2-7 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpaper1 libpixman-1-0 libsm6 libthai-data libthai0 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwmf0.2-7 libxaw7 libxcb-render0
  libxcb-shm0 libxmu6 libxrender1 libxt6 poppler-data python3-dateutil python3-jmespath python3-olefile python3-pil
  python3-roman x11-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fontconfig x11-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig x11-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 157 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/194 kB of archives.
After this operation, 698 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 143547 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../x11-common_1%3a7.7+19ubuntu14_all.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching nux-tools
Unpacking x11-common (1:7.7+19ubuntu14) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/x11-common_1%3a7.7+19ubuntu14_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating symbolic link './usr/bin/X11': Operation not permitted
Preparing to unpack .../fontconfig_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fontconfig (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fontconfig_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/fc-cache.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/fc-cache'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/x11-common_1%3a7.7+19ubuntu14_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fontconfig_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I changed the title to the relevant error. You should be checking why the upgrade cannot be unpacked, for example using `stat /usr/bin/X11` or `ls -l /usr/bin/X11` and the like. You may also want to run `apt autoremove` because those packages are not required anymore anyway.

Comment: Do you have file systems mounted read-only? (Show the output of `mount`.) Does `dmesg` show any errors related to a file system? Please [edit] your question to answer. Maybe you need to perform a file system check. See https://askubuntu.com/a/548772/1186757 Try `sudo touch /forcefsck` with a reboot first. If it displays errors and if the errors are not fixed, then you might have to edit the `FSCKFIX` line as well.